# How to create groups and allocate a quantity per group depending on maximum value per group?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a function that creates groups and allocates a quantity per group, depending on the user input.

For example:

```
// Input
User input: 150

// Rule
Maximum quantity per group: 100

// Created groups
Group 1: { quantity: 100 }
Group 2: { quantity: 50 }
```

**Goal**

This is my desired outcome:

`[{ quantity: 100 }, { quantity: 50 }]`

**What I have tried**

```js
function group(input, maximum) {
  let arr = (new Array(Math.floor(input / maximum))).fill(maximum);

  input % maximum && arr.push(input % maximum);

  console.log(arr);
}

group(150, 100);
```

**Output**

This will return me: `[100, 50]`.

Now I tried implementing this to output me an object:

```js
function group(input, maximum) {
  let arr = (new Array({quantity: Math.floor(input / maximum)})).fill(maximum);

  input % maximum && arr.push({quantity: input % maximum});

  console.log(arr);
}

group(150, 100);
```

**Output**

This returns me: `[100, { "quantity": 50 }]`.

`quantity` is only added to the second element, but not the first.

**Question**

How can I fix this, so all the array elements is an object?

Comment: You're very close to achieve your desired objective. In your first snippet, try this: `console.log(arr.map(quantity => ({quantity})));`

Comment: @jsN00b Brain's fried.. I can replace the `.fill(maximum)` with `.fill({quantity: maximum})`. But if I test: `group(150, 200)`, I get a completely different outcome :/

Comment: Fatigue is understandable. Have added an answer for your reference. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comment, the question is very close to the desired objective.

Here's one possible way to achieve the desired target structure.

```js
function group(input, maximum) {
  let arr = (new Array(Math.floor(input / maximum))).fill(maximum);

  input % maximum && arr.push(input % maximum);
  
  // instead of using "arr", simply transform it
  // by putting the number as an object with prop-name "quantity"
  console.log(arr.map(quantity => ({ quantity })));
}

group(150, 100);
```

Explanation added as inline comments in the above snippet.